# Remove newest redundant row and update timestamp

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm working with a SQLite database that receives large data dumps on a regular basis from several sources. Unfortunately, those sources aren't intelligent about what they dump, and I end up with a lot of repeated records from one time to the next. I'm looking for a way to remove these repeated records without affecting the records that have legitimately changed from the past dump to this one.

Here's the general structure of the data (_id is the primary key):

```
| _id | _dateUpdated | _dateEffective | _dateExpired | name | status | location |
|-----|--------------|----------------|--------------|------|--------|----------|
|  1  |  2016-05-01  |    2016-05-01  |     NULL     | Fred | Online |  USA     |
|  2  |  2016-05-01  |    2016-05-01  |     NULL     | Jim  | Online |  USA     |
|  3  |  2016-05-08  |    2016-05-08  |     NULL     | Fred | Offline|  USA     |
|  4  |  2016-05-08  |    2016-05-08  |     NULL     | Jim  | Online |  USA     |
|  5  |  2016-05-15  |    2016-05-15  |     NULL     | Fred | Offline|  USA     |
|  6  |  2016-05-15  |    2016-05-15  |     NULL     | Jim  | Online |  USA     |
```

I'd like to be able to reduce this data to something like this:

```
| _id | _dateUpdated | _dateEffective | _dateExpired | name | status | location |
|-----|--------------|----------------|--------------|------|--------|----------|
|  1  |  2016-05-01  |    2016-05-01  |  2016-05-07  | Fred | Online |  USA     |
|  2  |  2016-05-15  |    2016-05-01  |     NULL     | Jim  | Online |  USA     |
|  3  |  2016-05-15  |    2016-05-08  |     NULL     | Fred | Offline|  USA     |
```

The idea here is that rows 4, 5, and 6 exactly duplicate rows 2 and 3 except for the timestamps (I'd need to compare by all three fields - name, status, location). However, row 3 does not duplicate row 1 (status changed from Online to Offline), so the _dateExpired field is set in row 1, and row 3 becomes the most recent record.

I'm querying this table with something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Data WHERE
    date(_dateEffective) <= date("now")
    AND (_dateExpired IS NULL OR date(_dateExpired) > date("now"))
```

Is this sort of reduction possible in SQLite?

I am still a beginner to SQL and database design in general, so it's possible that I haven't structured the database in the best way. I'm open to suggestions there as well...I'm going for the ability to query data at a given point in time - for example, "what was Jim's status around 2016-05-06?"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So with every dump you want to also remove past records or maintain a growing records list?

Comment: I'd like to keep a growing list of records for historical data, but I only want to keep new records if they are unique from old ones. If a dump adds additional records that are identical to what I have already, I don't care about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a staging table where the dump file goes into a DumpTable (regularly cleaned out before each dump) and then an `INSERT...SELECT` query migrates to your final table.

Now the `SELECT` portion maintains a correlated subquery (to calculate new `[_dateExpired]` for needed rows) and derived table subquery (to filter out non-dups according to your criteria). Finally, the `LEFT JOIN...NULL` with FinalTable is to ensure no duplicate records are appended, assuming `[_id]` is a unique identifier. Below is the routine:

1. Clean Out DumpTable

   ```
   DELETE FROM DumpTable;
   ```
2. Run Dump Routine to be appended into DumpTable
3. Append Records to FinalTable

   ```
   INSERT INTO FinalTable ([_id], [_dateUpdated], [_dateEffective], [_dateExpired], 
                           [name], status, location)
   SELECT d.[_id], d.[_dateUpdated], d.[_dateEffective],     
          (SELECT Min(date(sub.[_dateEffective], '-1 day'))
             FROM DumpTable sub  
            WHERE sub.[name] = DumpTable.[name] 
              AND sub.[_dateEffective] > DumpTable.[_dateEffective]  
              AND sub.status <> DumpTable.status) As calcExpired 
          d.name, d.status, d.location
   FROM DumpTable d    

   INNER JOIN 
             (SELECT Min(DumpTable.[_id]) AS min_id, 
                     DumpTable.name, DumpTable.status 
                FROM DumpTable 
            GROUP BY DumpTable.name, DumpTable.status)  AS c     
    ON (c.name = d.name) 
   AND (c.min_id = d.[_id]) 
   AND (c.status = d.status)

   LEFT JOIN FinalTable f
      ON d.[_id] = f.[_id]
   WHERE f.[_id] IS NULL;

   -- INSERTED RECORDS:
   -- _id  _dateUpdated    _dateEffective  _dateExpired    name    status     location
   -- 1    2016-05-01      2016-05-01      2016-05-07      Fred    Online     USA
   -- 2    2016-05-01      2016-05-01                      Jim     Online     USA
   -- 3    2016-05-08      2016-05-08                      Fred    Offline    USA
   ```

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't thought about using a separate table, but this makes life a hundred times easier.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this sort of reduction possible in SQLite?

The answer to any "reduction" question in SQL is always Yes.  The trick is to find what axes you're reducing along.

Here's a partial solution to illustrate; it gives the first Online date for each name & location.

```
select min(_dateEffective) as start_date
    , name
    , location
from Data
where status = 'Online'
group by  
      name
    , location
```

With an outer join back to the table (on name & location) where the status is 'Offline' and the _dateEffective is greater than `start_date`, you get your `_dateExpired`.

> _id is the primary key

There is a commonly held misunderstanding that every table needs some kind of sequential "ID" number as a primary key.  The key you really care about is known as a *natural key*, 1 or more columns *in the data* that uniquely identify the data.  In your case, it looks to me like that's `_dateEffective, name, status, and location`.  At the very least, declare them `unique` to prevent accidental duplication.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'd never heard of a natural key before...sounds like something I'll need to look into. Are there disadvantages of having a numeric id field, other than the cost of storing one extra number with each row?